# How to set Java version to all users

Tags: linux, environment-variables, java, libraries, jdk

I set the `JAVA_HOME` parameters in the `etc/environment/` and when I do `echo $JAVA_HOME`, I can see the latest version which I have set. But when I do `java -version` it shows a different version, which is a little older and existed already on the machine.

```
linuxm_x6:/opt # java -version
java version "1.8.0_101"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)

linuxm_x6:/opt # echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib64/jvm/jdk1.8.0_131
```

How to change the Java version for all users as well?

Comment: Which distribution are you using, and how did you install/update java?  I'll bet that if you do `ls -l \`which java\`` it will be a link pointing to something in /etc/defaults which will be a link pointing elsewhere...

Comment: @ivanivan OpenSUSE

Comment: Quick google shows you'll need to update the alternatives/defaults like I suggested - check https://www.unixmen.com/install-java-8-opensuse-13-x-sles-servers/

Comment: @ivanivan means the symlinks and which you can check via `ll -h /etc/alternatives/java` and `ll -h /usr/java/`